# font changing when trying to convert PDF to PowerPoint (PPT)

Tags: pdf, fonts, powerpoint, adobe, selectpdf

In my project there is a function to produce a PDF file based on a custom template for each customer. in order to do that I use SelectPDF, then add in ASP.NET Razor files and exporting it as a PDF. sometimes I'm asked for specific fonts, so I add them to my .LESS file for the template using @font-face.

now I have a task to create a PDF that may be later converted to a PowerPoint file via Adobe. the problem is that Adobe doesn't know how to handle the custom fonts I use.

for example, this is what I get with the PDF:

[image]

and this is what happens after I convert it via Adobe:

[image]

is it keep the custom fonts from the PDF export to the PowerPoint file

Answer (score 0):

generally for such a font to be supported it should be 100% embeded as a font not subset as a range of characters.

Then the Full TTF name should be in the fontlist
[image]
[image]

If the pdf2pptx converter is doing its job correctly, and has access for fallback, it should then use RockwellNova, as seen here without embed and with embed

[image]

however since PPTX rarely embed the fonts it will be down to the system substitution when viewing the pptx.

[image]

[image]